# SQL query is returning the multiple lines of the same fields

Tags: sql

This is my code below and im trying to return all of the columns in SELECT who have a category number of 4. But when i do so i am getting the correct answer but it is repeating itself over 100 times! Does anyone know why this would be happening?

```
SELECT sr.CondoID, cu.LocationNum, sr.EstHours, sr.SpentHours, o.OwnerNum, o.LastName
FROM service_request sr, owner o, condo_unit cu
WHERE CategoryNum = '4';
```

[Service_request table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZNnS.png)

[Condo_Unit table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEH2l.png)

[Owner table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WK3L.png)

Comment: You are currently doing a _cross join_ between all 3 tables, hence the large and unexpected result set size.  Please include table structure if you want help with a correct query here.

Comment: I have added photos of my tables now

Comment: Please provide data  in text format or atleast make it part of the question instead attachment.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to copy all the data

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment you see the result which is a `cross join` between all the table rows in the from clause. So you need to join them to get related rows within the tables,

As I see in your images and because the expected result is missing I would just use simple `join` (can be changed to `left join` if requirement asks for it  from your side) and write the query as,

```
select sr.CondoID, cu.LocationNum, sr.EstHours, sr.SpentHours, o.OwnerNum, o.LastName
  from service_request sr
  join condo_unit cu
    on cu.condoid = sr.condoid
  join owner o
    on o.ownernum = cu.ownernun
 where sr.categoryNum = 4;
```

P.S. From the image the `categoryNum` doesn't send to be character so I removed the `''` around it. You can put it back if it's a `varchar` column.